# Transaction timeout exception when using ehCache

Tags: spring, ehcache, jta

I have ehCache configured in my application which depends on jtaTransaction

```
<bean id="ehcacheManager"
            class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
            depends-on="jtaTransactionManagerLookup"
            p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache/ehcache.xml"/>
```

Transaction beans are defined below

```
<bean id="jtaTransactionManagerLookup" class="cdot.jta.TransactionManagerLookup"
        c:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager"
    />

<bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager" />
            <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction"/>
            <property name="transactionSynchronizationRegistryName" value="java:TransactionSynchronizationRegistry"/>
            <property name="defaultTimeout" value="300"/>
        </bean>
```

I tried including the property `defaultTimeout` as well but still running into transaction issues.

Error Trace:

```
org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.transaction.TransactionTimeoutException: transaction timed out
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.get(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.get(ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.get(NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.CacheHelper.fromSharedCache(CacheHelper.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.CacheHelper.fromSharedCache(CacheHelper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:598)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
    at cdot.base.HibernateProxy.load(HibernateProxy.java:458)
    at cdot.base.HibernateProxy.load(HibernateProxy.java:431)
    at cdot.base.HibernateProxy$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3d33b231.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at cdot.base.HibernateProxy$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a28fa869.load(<generated>)
    at cdot.base.HibernateDAO.findBusinessObject(HibernateDAO.java:150)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.services.weather.ccic.facade.CcicFacade.getRoadConditions(CcicFacade.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor158.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.getRoadConditions(Unknown Source)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.services.weather.route.facade.WeatherRouteFacade.getWeatherSourceDTOList(WeatherRouteFacade.java:998)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.getWeatherSourceDTOList(Unknown Source)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.delegate.controllers.WeatherRouteController.getAllEnabledWeatherRouteRoadConditions(WeatherRouteController.java:300)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.delegate.facade.AnnotationDelegateController.executeInternal(AnnotationDelegateController.java:287)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.delegate.facade.AnnotationDelegateController.processAction(AnnotationDelegateController.java:232)
    at springboot.config.web.RemotingConfig$AuthenticatingDelegateServiceWrapper.processAction(RemotingConfig.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.processAction(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.remoting.rmi.ContextPropagatingRemoteInvocation.invoke(ContextPropagatingRemoteInvocation.java:113)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:39)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiBasedExporter.invoke(RmiBasedExporter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper.invoke(RmiInvocationWrapper.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.transaction.TransactionTimeoutException: transaction timed out
    at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.XATransactionStore.assertNotTimedOut(XATransactionStore.java:278)
    at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.XATransactionStore.getFromUnderlyingStore(XATransactionStore.java:393)
    at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.XATransactionStore.get(XATransactionStore.java:304)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.AbstractCopyingCacheStore.get(AbstractCopyingCacheStore.java:95)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.TxCopyingCacheStore.get(TxCopyingCacheStore.java:33)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1734)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.get(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:112)
    ... 91 more
```

Comment: Resolved the issue by specifying the timeout directly in the ehcache.xml <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         defaultTransactionTimeoutInSeconds="300"
         dynamicConfig="true">

Answer (score 0):

Please add the default timeout in the ehcache.xml file

```
<defaultCache
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        statistics="false">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</defaultCache>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by directly specifying the default Transaction timeout in ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         defaultTransactionTimeoutInSeconds="300"
         dynamicConfig="true">
```

Unsure on why the ehcache is not picking up the default value specified in the transaction bean.